# JSON parse functions are not parsing

Tags: javascript, java, json

I am running a Javascript function on the latest version of Mozilla which receives a string which I want to convert to a JSON object. The conversion seems to be failing.

The string is being generated on the server side in a Java function:

```
         result = "[{ \"userID\": 1 \"firstName\":\"John\" \"lastName\":\"Sheridan\" }{ \"userID\": 2 \"firstName\":\"Michael\" \"lastName\":\"Geribaldi\" }]";
```

(note that I am attempting to return an array of values for a list).

The code on the client side is the ajax callback shown below:

```
var successFunc = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    alert("Data: "+data);

    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert("Object: "+obj);
}
```

Apparently, the data is coming back to the callback and is being displayed in its string form, but the JSON parser is failing because the second alert is failing to appear. I am sure something is wrong with my string but am having trouble figuring out what. The debugger is not telling me anything, I am just seeing a silent failure.

I have also attempted this using the JSON.parser() function. I am seeing the same thing. I am making a mistake somewhere. Can someone tell me where?

Comment: Your string is not in proper format.... missing `,` after `\"userID\": 1` and `\"firstName\":\"John\"`

Answer (score 2):

Your json is not valid, you are missing comma

In order to parse your json should be like this

```
[
 { "userID": 1, "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Sheridan" },
 { "userID": 2, "firstName":"Michael", "lastName":"Geribaldi" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a format where data is in `key:value` pairs separeted by `,` and key and value are enclosed in `double quotes`, where objects are enclosed in `{}` braces and array is enclosed in `[]` hope you have got the your mistake that where your json is lacking.

```
  "[{ 
    \"userID\": 1 ,
    \"firstName\":\"John\",
    \"lastName\":\"Sheridan\",
     },
    { 
    \"userID\": 2 ,
    \"firstName\":\"Michael\",
    \"lastName\":\"Geribaldi\" }]"
```